# I need help in the excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I need help in the formula.

Really appreciate your help. I've attached an example (below) for what I'm looking for. I have unique IDs for each project but there are multiple project managers attached to same IDs.

```
ID      Project      Project 
        Manager 1    Manager 2
B250    Chris        Julia
B291    Chris        Alex
C951    Fiona        Julia
```

Project manager 1 is leading the project and project manager 2 is just assisting. 
Now here what I want to do. I want to create a formula that when I choose project manager name lets say "Chris" it should say "Lead" and when I choose project manager "Julia" it should say "Assist".

Keep that in mind that I am already pulling data from a source using the index and small function and its working fine in getting all the other relevant information when I select the project manager example.

when I select Chris it gives me below details.

```
B250      Project details         budget            hours                 Lead
```

Here the problem is that same ID (B250) is using by another project manager with different hours and working as an assistant so when I select Julia who is an assistant here what I get.

```
B250      Project details         budget            hours                Lead
```

(This is the issue because she is not the lead and index function is pulling data from the same row in the dataset).

Hope I have explained it well.

Comment: Where is the formula?

Comment: Please try to choose a title that actually describes your problem in something less than 100% vague terms. Also, yes, what ^ he said; if you want help with code, post the code, otherwise the question is off-topic.

Comment: Please let us know what you mean by when you "select" Chris or "select" Julia. Also show us where this other information is coming from (project details, budget, hours)

Answer (score 2):

Use Choose to return the correct word:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(F2,INDEX(B:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0),0),0),"Lead","Assist")
```

[image]